# meaning of :: in angular formly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

i'm trying to learn how to work with angular firmly and i'm having trouble understanding some of the syntax used in the guides and examples on the [official website](http://angular-formly.com/#/).
when defining a button form control i saw this template:

```
<div><button type="{{::to.type}}" class="btn btn-{{::to.btnType}}" ng-click="onClick($event)">{{to.text}}</button></div>
```

my question is: what is the meaning of "::" before the "to.type" and "to.btnType"?
how is it being used?
how is that different from defining it like this:

```
<a ng-class="{'btn-primary': to.isPrimary, active: to.isActive}" class="btn, btn-default"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [one-time binding expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding), it stops the proliferation of watchers which can often cause performance issues.

Here is some useful reading: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the one-time binding expression.

In your case, when `to.type` will have a value set, it will be updated in the HTML template. Then, if the value `to.type` changes again, the HTML template won't be updated with the new value.

More information can be found on AngularJS website at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding.